# How to use a android device to a Beacon by the library android-beacon-library?

Tags: android, altbeacon

```
BeaconParser beaconParser = new BeaconParser()
    .setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25");
Beacon beacon = new Beacon.Builder()
    .setId1("2f234454-cf6d-4a0f-adf2-f4911ba9ffa6")
    .setId2("1")
    .setId3("2")
    .setManufacturer(0x0118)
    .setTxPower(-59)
    .setDataFields(Arrays.asList(new Long[]{0l}))
    .build();
beaconTransmitter.startAdvertising(beacon, new AdvertiseCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onStartFailure(int errorCode) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Advertisement start failed with code: " + errorCode);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartSuccess(AdvertiseSettings settingsInEffect) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Advertisement start succeeded.");
    }
 });
```

Run this,The log "Advertisement start succeeded." is shown, is success.
But,mBeaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region); not find the altBeacon.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot detect a beacon on the same device that is transmitting the packets.  This is not a limitation specific tothe Android Beacon Library, it is just how Bluetooth LE works.  It is common for radio hardware systems to be designed not to receive their own transmissions.

Comment: ,Thank you very much for your reply, I use another Android phone to detect，but not find,  I download some apks to detect, Is also not detected, Please help me check the code above is correct, I not sure the parameters of setBeaconLayout, setId1, setId2, setId3, setManufacturer is correct, because I want to use the android phone as a Beacon device,  I am not sure how to write these parameters, My android device is 6.0. Look forward to your reply, Thanks.

Comment: I use the apk of Locate beacon can find the beacon, I don't know how to use the method of setDataFields and how to write the parameter, please help me, Thanks!

Comment: If the locate app detects the beacon, but your code does not, then the problem is with the detection code.  Please post that code.